# Problems deserializing List of Object within Class

Tags: dart

Having a few challenges with deserialization of a List of Class within a parent, simple objects no issue but certain I am making it more difficult than it needs to be.

Example code -

```
class Workout {
  String uid;
  String id;
  String name;
  String folderid;
  int order = 0;
  List<WorkoutExercise> workoutExercises = [];

  Workout({
    required this.uid,
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.folderid,
    required this.workoutExercises,
  });


  Workout.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot, this.uid)
      : name = snapshot['n'] as String,
        id = snapshot['i'] as String,
        folderid = snapshot['f'] as String,
        order = snapshot['o'] as int,
        workoutExercises = snapshot['e'] as List<WorkoutExercise> ;
```

Obviously the last line is incorrect, any help appreciated.

Various methods tried but no expected end result

Comment: I recommend reading: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by mapping the value as `WorkoutExcercise`.

Try this:

```
workoutExercises = (snapshot['e'] as List<dynamic>)
        .map((exerciseMap) => WorkoutExercise.fromMap(exerciseMap))
        .toList();
```

I hope this will work !!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I managed to do a lot of hacking and converted my code to use the auto generation using json_annotation